# To render auto populated search result Debounce is not working in React and i am not able to call my debounce inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, debouncing

Please let me know where i am doing mistake as i am new to React and i am implementing the concepts for the first time in the live project

> **This is place where data is getting processed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple notes I have about your code:

1. Use either debounce or throttle. But don't use them together. You can find a very good explanation of both techniques [here](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).
2. Remove your dependancies from useEffect. In your case useEffect will execute every time input changes + every time the fetch is set. From this code that you posted there is actually no point of you having useEffect. Render can be handled by useMemo.
3. useMemo must have its own dependancy array. In your case its executing on every render. So you need to move its dependancies from useEffect to useMemo. For example you could do
   `const inputHasChanged = useMemo(() => debounce(rxCometGetFindUsers, 500), [inputValue]);`

So to get this to work you do:

I have not used "Autocomplete" before so I'm not sure what options you must include.

```
 return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="find-user"
      className="autoCompSearch"
      style={{ width: 370 }}
      getOptionLabel={option => getValues(option)}
      defaultValue={defaultObj || ""}
      filterOptions={x => x}
      options={options}
      autoComplete
      includeInputInList
      freeSolo
      disableOpenOnFocus
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          placeholder="GLOBAL SEARCH"
          fullWidth
          onChange={handleChange}
          onKeyDown={onKeyDownHandler} // I would remove this, dont see a reason why you would need this and onChange
        />
      )}
```

This is fine

```
    const handleChange = event => {
event.preventDefault();
console.log("User has entered" +event.target.value);
setInputValue(event.target.value);
 };
```

Next, you could use [`debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) function from [lodash](https://lodash.com/) but the problem is that you probably have an async function, since you fetch something. Debounce from lodash is not able to handle this behaviour.
So you need to use a [p-debounce](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-debounce).

```
import pDebounce from 'p-debounce';

const inputHasChanged = useMemo(() => pDebounce(rxCometGetFindUsers, 500), [inputValue]);

const rxCometGetFindUsers = async = () =>{

let newData = await ... //do your fetching
setOptions(newData)
}
```

Comment: Getting error :                                                                                                                        TypeError: func.apply is not a function
(anonymous function)
  100 |     if (timer) clearTimeout(timer)
  101 |     timer = setTimeout(() => {
  102 |       timer = null
> 103 |       func.apply(context, args);
      | ^  104 |     }, 500)
  105 |   }
  106 | }

Comment: Can u help me in putting all things together like removing useEffect and adding its code to useMemo

Comment: Sure. Where do you get your "Autocomplete" component from. Is it the one from material-ui?

Comment: Yes from there only i got this